# Problem when starting gunicorn with .sh (No module named '.0')

Tags: flask, sh, gunicorn

I'm trying to start a flask application with gunicorn but i'm facing an issue.

When starting it from command line it works fine with this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --preload --certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server_name.net/fullchain.pem --keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server_name.net/privkey.pem -w 17
-b 0.0.0.0:9090 wsgi:app
```

The same command from a .sh script raise an error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 221, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 70, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.setup(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 118, in setup
    self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 65, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 372, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named '.0'
```

Both cli and .sh are run as root.

The same script works fine on a different server so i guess there is a problem with the environment.

I tried to add in the script the following lines at the beginning of the script without success:

```
$PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/app
```

and

```
$PWD=/path/to/my/app
```

This is the wsgi file i'm using:

```
from api import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem. The following script seems to be working:

```
cd /path_to_app/
gunicorn --certfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/server_name.net/fullchain.pem --keyfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/server_name.net/privkey.pem -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:9090 wsgi:app
```